# how to access may-to-many relationship in django?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have two model

```
class ClassProfile(models.Model):
    classname = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    class = models.ManyToManyField('ClassProfile')
```

I try to get all the famulymember like this

```
 class = Class.objects.get(pk=1)
 members = class.userprofile_set.all()
```

this will rasie an error

```
'ClassProfile' object has no attribute 'userprofile_set'
```

what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think django uses CamelCase anywhere? By default, the reverse accessor is `lowercaseclsname_set`

So `class.userprofile_set.all()` should do it.

Comment: @chenliang did you restart the shell session? Paste the output of dir(class) please

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that it is not a good idea to name a variable `class`, I think you have a typo in this line:

```
class = Class.objects.get(pk=1)
```

You probably meant:

```
class = ClassProfile.objects.get(pk=1)
```